Вывод уникальных значений массива C#

Ваша программа так же получает на вход два числа в строковом формате, но теперь они  могут быть разной длины. Найдите все уникальные элементы первого числа (значения, которые встречаются  только 1 раз в обоих массивах)
Пример:
12335
1458
В данном случае уникально число 2 - оно существует в одном экземпляре
1 и 5 есть во втором массиве, а 3 встречается дважды в первом
В итоге ответ:
"Уникально число 2".

я написал следующий код
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
public class MainClass
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string num1 = Console.ReadLine();
        string num2 = Console.ReadLine();
        string allnum = num1 + num2;
        var diff = allnum.Except(num2);
        foreach (var s in diff)
            Console.WriteLine($"Уникально число {s} ");
    }
}

Как убрать из ответа повторяющиеся значения, так как они не будут являться уникальными?

если я правильно понял, вам нужно просто склеить 2 числа, затем применить группировку и отфильтровать группы по количеству элементов. Смотрите GroupBy и Where

allnum.Except(num2).GroupBy(x => x).Where(g => g.Count() == 1).Select(g => g.Key);

Не в обиду другим отвечающим, но я что-то в шоке с качества ответов на элементарный вопрос про множества (весеннее обострение?). Посмотрите в сторону коллекции Set, чтобы понять, как Enumerable.Distinct под капотом работает. И ни в коем случае не лезьте пока в стринг пулы, переопределения string.Empty и следующие из них obect.ReferenceEquals вместо string.IsNullOrEmpty из ответа ниже.

@aa_talanin только что понял, что дичь предложил, исправил.

@aepot, вы так тонко троллите?) Или я сам вашу ошибку повторяю и не понимаю, почему простой Distinct не сработал бы

@aa_talanin потому что автор сказал "убрать из ответа повторяющиеся значения, так как они не будут являться уникальными", то есть не просто выкинуть дубликаты, а вообще неуникальные убрать. Я так понял. Условие задачи тоже это подтверждает.

@aa_talanin совершенно с вами согласен, я и сам шокирован не меньше вашего, потому что можно вместо массива счётчиков на 128 интов замутить битвектор на двух лонгах, но тут опять программистская дилемма - или жертвовать оперативкой и слегка погореть на коллекторе, но не терять счётчики, или совсем быстро улететь внебеса на двух лонгах вместо массива? и конечно же к чёрту стрингбилдер - тут без стекаллока не обойтись, потому как нужно что бы оно взлетело с таким ускорением, что бы пробило пространственно-временную дыру

Спасибо, что вписываетесь в мой учебный блуд. Преклоняюсь перед вашими знаниями! Но. Я изучаю программирование вторую неделю, а так то я по образованию юрист и с программированием последний раз знакомился классе в 8 (2006 году так то) при изучении Паскаля) неужели нет каких-то простых методов отсеивания дубликатов, а точнее вывода в консоль исключительно уникальных значений массива) не думаю, что те, кто создали курс, который я прохожу навесили бы на абсолютно нулевых курсантов такие сложные задачи)

namespace UniqueChars_v0
{
    public sealed class UniqueChars
    {
        public readonly int[] CharCounters;

        public UniqueChars(string firstString, string secondString)
        {
            CharCounters = new int[128];

            // if (firstString is not null)
            if (!object.ReferenceEquals(firstString, null))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < firstString.Length; i++)
                    CharCounters[firstString[i]]++;

                // if (secondString is not null)
                if (!object.ReferenceEquals(secondString, null))
                    for (int i = 0; i < secondString.Length; i++)
                        if (CharCounters[secondString[i]] > 0)
                            CharCounters[secondString[i]]++;
            }
        }
        [CompilerServices.MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public bool HasUniqueChar(int charIndex)
        {
            return CharCounters[charIndex] == 1;
        }
        [CompilerServices.MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public bool HasUniqueNumber(int charIndex)
        {
            return charIndex >= '0' && charIndex <= '9'
                && CharCounters[charIndex] == 1;
        }

        public sealed override string ToString()
        {
            var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder("[ ");

            for (int i = 0; i < CharCounters.Length; i++)
                if (HasUniqueChar(i)) { sb.Append((char)i).Append(' '); }

            return sb.Append(']').ToString();
        }
        public string UniqueNumbersToString()
        {
            var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder("[ ");

            for (int i = '0'; i <= '9'; i++)
                if (HasUniqueChar(i)) { sb.Append((char)i).Append(' '); }

            return sb.Append(']').ToString();
        }
    }
}

Usage and Tests
                                                               Output
var unique0 = new UniqueChars(null, null);
System.Console.WriteLine(unique0);                             [ ]

var unique1 = new UniqueChars("", "");
System.Console.WriteLine(unique1);                             [ ]

var unique2 = new UniqueChars("0", "0");
System.Console.WriteLine(unique2);                             [ ]

var unique3 = new UniqueChars("12345", "12345");
System.Console.WriteLine(unique3);                             [ ]

var unique4 = new UniqueChars("12335", "1458");
System.Console.WriteLine(unique4);                             [ 2 ]
System.Console.WriteLine(unique4.UniqueNumbersToString());     [ 2 ]
System.Console.WriteLine(unique4.HasUniqueNumber('1'));        False
System.Console.WriteLine(unique4.HasUniqueNumber('2'));        True

var unique5 = new UniqueChars("Hello", "World");
System.Console.WriteLine(unique5);                             [ H e ]
System.Console.WriteLine(unique5.HasUniqueChar('e'));          True
System.Console.WriteLine(unique5.HasUniqueNumber('e'));        False

var unique6 = new UniqueChars("Ticket 12335", "Ticket 1458");
System.Console.WriteLine(unique6);                             [ 2 ]

var unique7 = new UniqueChars("tICKET 12335", "Ticket 1458");
System.Console.WriteLine(unique7);                             [ 2 C E I K ]
System.Console.WriteLine(unique7.UniqueNumbersToString());     [ 2 ]


!object.ReferenceEquals(firstString, null) = firstString is not null

это хорошо, но не везде завезли [точнее - не всем завезли], помечу в комментариях

Тогда !string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstString); но я бы предложил игнорировать наличие Framework 4.x, если в вопросе не указано явно, что нужно это старьё. Я свои ответы так пишу, пока проблем с этим не было. Кстати, если класс sealed, то методы запечатывать смысла нет, ведь невозможно отнаследоваться от него. Ещё кстати можно firstString?.Length > 0.

тут две программистских дилеммы, встречалось такое что string.IsNullOrEmpty() не работает при отключенном стринг-пуле и/или [целенаправленно] переломанном стринг-пуле и это конечно редко встречается, а вторая дилемма - это двойная проверка, т.к. в string.IsNullOrEmpty() проверяется длина и в цикле [во входе в цикл] проверяется длина, то дёргается два раза проверка длины - оставлена одна проверка длины, непосредственно во входе в циклы

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/String.cs#L499-L502 - вряд-ли стринг пул может на это влиять. Ну тогда банальный != null сработает.

смотрите, я встречал такое где string.Empty глобально переопределили [да, это зло, но если работает и всё потестировано и всех устраивает - то проблем нет], проблема в другом, методы работы со строками в старых рантаймах похоже были оптимизированы и сначала сравнивали в методах ссылки на строки, но тут и вылазит проблема, раньше было сравнение на пустоту через RefEquals, но пустая строка - это же уже не пустая строка, её ж переопределили глобально, а в методе IsNullOrEmpty так и осталось сравнение по ссылкам - вот оно выдавало некорректное поведение метода

т.е. по идее в новых рантаймах должно быть два метода IsNullOrEmpty, при штатной работе стринг-пула можно сравнивать строки через ссылки в методе IsNullOrEmpty, либо если некий флаг включился [стринг-пул разломан], то начинает работать IsNullOrEmpty непосредственно через string.Length, а на самом деле нужен пользовательский настраиваемый стринг-пул

Кто мне переопределит string.Empty кроме меня самого? То что где-то кто-то сам себе нагадил не значит, что теперь надо всю жизнь код писать с учётом того случая. Это параноя называется. .NET через рефлексию и IL хуки можно весь испохабить, если захотеть, и что теперь, вообще код не писать на C#?

это не похабство, это отсутствие возможностей

А почему ваш код считает, что код символа меньше 128?

коды символов '0'-'9' меньше 128, т.е. '0'-'9' точно влезает в таблицу счётчиков, и округлено до 128 для тестов; таблицу счётчиков можно сделать на десяти интах, но тогда потребуются офсеты; а на самом деле тут нужен дополнительный хитрый аллокатор на бУкетах массивов, на нём можно охватить весь юникод, и каждая аллокация под таблицу счётчиков много памяти не съест

например поиск в такой хитрой таблице аллокаций [а это по сути поиск и есть] только реализованный практически [почти] через прямой доступ к бУкетам микро-массивов - это ассоциированный поиск в районе ~120 миллионов чаров в соответственно ~120 миллионах строках в секунду на ядро на проце под 4ггц, и это весьма впечатляющий результат для дот.нета

Вообще вряд-ли автору надо 120 миллионов чаров. Я подозреваю что и со словарём ему было бы очень сложно.

Кол-во символов в строке можно проверить, деля строку методом Split(), по размеру Length полученного массива разделенных частей исходной строки. Если символ делит строку на более чем две части, то соответственно таких символов в строке несколько. Один символ делит строку на две части.
string.Concat(num1.Except(num2).Where(c => num1.Split(c).Length == 2));


Строка это массив символов, поэтому для того чтобы использовать Except правильно, вы можете ваши строки преобразовать сперва в массивы и получить вашу заветную разницу.
upd. Удаляем дубликаты из первой строки
Пример кода
    var items1 = "12335".Select(x=> x).GroupBy(x=> x).Where(x=> x.Count() == 1).Select( x=> x.Key);
    var items2 = "1458".Select(x=> x);
    
    foreach(var c in items1.Except(items2))
        Console.WriteLine(c);


Select(x=> x) зачем? Если убрать, ничего не поменяется.
